# mails send if condition is true using python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtp

we setup raspberry pi to measure server room temperature and save the out put in text file in this format `"Temp: 24.0 C  Humidity: 67.0 %"` (updates every 2 seconds) using python script .

now I am looking for python code to read temperature value (e.g 24.0) from text file and send me a emails if condition is true like(Temp>35.0) else do nothing and exit.

I am new in python so please help me out , we have already written emails code and its working , just enable the requested above condition in this below code.

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
fromaddr = "sender@gmail.com"
toaddr = "recipient@gmail.com"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Alert: Server Room  " 
body = "Server room current temprature is : "
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "password")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

This scripts will be run using `cron` tab.

Comment: Read the file then the line split with `Humidity`. Take first part the split it with `space` get the `temp`value from the list convert it to `(int)` and use it however you want.

Comment: If you are only just learning Python, you should concentrate on the currently supported and recommended version of the language, which is Python 3. Version 2 was originally slated to be end-of-lifed earlier this year, though it got a couple of years more in the respirator to help those who already had a heavy investment in the old version.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that something like this would do:

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText


def send_email(temperature):
    fromaddr = "sender@gmail.com"
    toaddr = "recipient@gmail.com"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = "Alert: Server Room  "
    body = "Server room current temprature is : " + temperature
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, "password")
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()


f = open("temp_log.txt", "r")
content = f.read()
temp = content.split(' ')[1]
if float(temp) > 35:
    send_email(temp)
```

Comment: hi @cyphics, what changes we can do in above code if the email data we want to send is in dataframe df rather than reading from a file

Answer (score 1):

In first go it looks, but the complete reliable solution is reasonably difficult to implement.  The code you are asking for might look as below:

```
with open ('temp.txt', 'r',  encoding='utf-8') as temp:
 for line in temp:
       try: 
           temperature = float(line.split()[1])
           if temperature > 35.0: 
                 #SENDEMAIL 
           else: 
               pass
       except: 
          pass
```

Here `temp.txt` is the file from your raspberry.

What you need to worry about:

1. Reading file in realtime.
2. You should develop a logic - every read
   should read the new part of file. For old part, you already sent the
   email. Else you will flood the mailbox with huge emails.